# Finding correlations between categories using Correlations matrix and heatmap with dendrogram

Tags: correlation, python, dendrogram, heatmap

I have a dataset with 5000 obs grouped by category:

- 1: science
- 0.5: philosophy
- -0.5: medicine
- -1: law

I would like to run some statistics to find correlations among variables within the groups, for example student's age, student's school, student's interests, student's publications and so on.
I have continuous and categorical variables:

```
Student  Age   School            Interests  Publications   Score     Category
1         23    A                computers       Y          12.5      science
2         22    B                sport           N          11.2      medicine
3         26    A                movies          Y          20.4      law
4         28    A                reading         N          25        philosophy
5         21    C                sport           Y          12.4      law
6         24    B                food            N          24.6      medicine
7         25    A                books           Y          22.5      science
...
```

I have selected the features I am mostly interested in, splitting into categorical, numerical and boolean (Y/N) and calculate the correlation matrix after transforming categorical into numerical:

```
categorical=['Category','Interests','School']
numerical=['Age','Score']
boolean=['Publications']

df = pd.get_dummies(net, columns = categorical)
corr = df.corr()

sns.heatmap(corr, annot=False, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

Also, I have tried to calculate a correlation heat map with dendrogram:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme(color_codes=True)

newdf =df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
l=newdf.columns

for i in l:
    res=newdf[i].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
    if res.iloc[0]>=70:
        del newdf[i]
        
category = newdf.pop("Category")
cl = dict(zip(category.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = category.map(cl)
g = sns.clustermap(newdf,  standard_scale=1, row_colors=row_colors)
```

However I have met the following difficulties:

- Should I include or not include the Category field in the correlation/heatmap?
- How should I interpret the dendrogram in the heat map?

Comment: Could you please explain why you are binning ("grouping") numerical variables?  Your stated objective appears to be "calculate correlations" and that usually is not accomplished well by binning.

Comment: thanks for the clarification whuber. I was wondering if it would have been better to consider binning the numerical variables in this case, even if I have been considering  correlations